# Draw a buffer around the world map while preserving national borders

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm quite advanced in using GIS, but I haven't found a solution to this problem yet. I have a few million dots showing a tweet location, several hundred thousand of which are outside the country's borders (see screenshot). I need to know which tweet was sent in which country, so a buffer is the ideal solution. Unfortunately, I don't know how to just draw a buffer along the outer borders of the world (and not around the entire countries), so that I can see afterwards in which country the tweet was sent. So a dissolve is not what I can use I think. Any tips or tools?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It looks like you just need some better borders

Comment: Where did you obtain your borders layer?

Comment: How do you know some aren't from people tweeting from boats?

Comment: I got my shapefile here: https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/export/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a buffer, you can simply identify to nearest polygon to each point. On the point layer, use the expression `overlay_nearest('polygon_layer',"fieldname")[0]` and replace the names of the `polygon_layer` and `fieldname` with the values you have.

---

*Remark: Be aware, however, that distances in a worldwide projection tend to be heavily distorted and - based on how far away the points are from the polygons - this will result in wrong country names for these points. You can't avoid this problem then by using different projections for each part of the world, like UTM zones.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question but maybe you can first extract the points that don't intersect any countries (which you call "out of world"). Then you can buffer around the countries and then add the 'country_name' attribute only on the extracted points.

Comment: Or maybe join the point to the closest country as buffer around country will overlap

Comment: Yes, with the NNJoin plug-in for example